# Как с помощью before перед пунктом есть в наличии отрисовать на css галочку?

Tags: html, css

Как с помощью before перед пунктом "есть в наличии" отрисовать на css галочку? Пробовал в контент подставить код галочки \2714, но это не то. Пример галочки вот такой https://i.stack.imgur.com/L07wY.png, но с закруглёнными краями (можно и без). По высоте 8 пикселей, по ширине 12

Comment: А где сам пункт? Он есть в наличии?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот простой пример галочки на CSS с помощью псевдоэлемента `:before`:

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px;
  padding-left: 45px;
  line-height: 64px;
}

div:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 32px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 32px;
  height: 16px;
  border-right: 4px solid black;
  border-top: 4px solid black;
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}
```

```html
<div>Текст</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете воспользоваться например [fontawesome](https://fontawesome.com/), взять [такую](https://fontawesome.com/icons/check?style=solid) иконку и засунуть её в псевдоэлемент - [codepen](https://codepen.io/grdnk/pen/qBaLaPj)

```css
.avail::before {
  content: '\f00c';
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  font-weight: 900;
  color: green;
  margin-right: 7px;
}
```

```html
<p class="avail">Есть в наличии</p>
```